# Java : Cast String Array to an Object

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to cast String Array to an Object.

```
Object string="[FIBER,CABLE]";
String[] strArray = (String[])string;
```

I got ClassCastException.

I can get by splitting str by slash and comma

```
Object string="[FIBER,CABLE]";
String[] strArray = ((String)string).split("[,\\]\\[]");

for(int i=1;i<strArray.length;i++)
    System.out.println(strArray[i]);
```

I wanted to know "**Is there any better way to do it?**"

Comment: That depends on what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: Why are you using `Object string = "[FIBER,CABLE]";` and not `String string = "[FIBER,CABLE]";`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I'm getting it as an Object from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the leading `[` and the trailing `]` *before* you splt the string.

```
Object obj = "[FIBER,CABLE]";

String str = (String) obj;
if (! str.startsWith("[") || ! str.endsWith("]"))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad data: " + str);
String[] strArray = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(",", -1);

for (String s : strArray)
    System.out.println(s);
```

*Output*

```
FIBER
CABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you currently have has an empty string in the 1st array position.

I would do this instead:

```
Object string = "[FIBER,CABLE]";

// cleaner to just cast it in a separate statement.
String s = (String) string;

// replace the "[" and "]" with "" and split on ","
String[] strArray = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");

// from i = 0 and not i = 1
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++)
    System.out.println(strArray[i]);
```

**Output**:

```
FIBER
CABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct fix here would be to refactor the database so that you aren't storing arrays in text fields but rather as separate rows in a table. In saying this, I assume you don't have access to the process which inserts into the database and therefore can't do anything about it.

Your solution looks good given the problem at hand.